# Как выбирать действия в адаптере в зависимости от активити

Tags: android, activity, recyclerview, adapter, cardview

у меня один адаптер и два активити. И хочу чтоб в каждом из этих активити отображались разные переходы по клику на item.

```
 itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("event_id", item.event.getId());
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    ((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.push_to_back);
                } else {

                    Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View) itemHolder.mTitleView, "event_title");
                    Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create((View) itemHolder.mInterestViewColor, "event_interest_bg");
                    Pair<View, String> p3 = Pair.create((View) itemHolder.mImageView, "ivent_image");
                    Pair<View, String> p4 = Pair.create((View) itemHolder.mInterestTitle, "event_interest_name");
                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, p1, p2, p3, p4);
                    context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                }
            }
        });
```

Как сделать выбор, если он находится в активити1, то по нажатию на item, переходит на одну страницу, если находится в активти2, то по нажатию на этот Же item, но в другую страницу.

Item это отдельный layout, для recyclerview.

Comment: вашу задачу можно решить многими путями, но глядя по коду, у вас проблема таится немного глубже)

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei и как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Получите информацию и имя у текущей запущенной активити, и делайте проверку если это activity1 -> EventActivity, если это другая переход activity2 -> InfoActivity/

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei как можно получать данную информацию. Меня это больше всего интересует

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае проще и архитектурно правильно прокинуть интерфейс из адаптера и регистрировать его в вызывающей активити, чем вешать действия слушателей прямо в адаптере. Данный подход позволит реализовать любую уникальную логику по клику в каждой вызывающей активити, без всяких костылей и нагромождения вариантов переходов в кликере адаптера. Примерный код (исключены все методы не относящиеся к реализации):

```
class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <SomeAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    interface OnCardClickListener {
        void onCardClick(View view,  int position, boolean isValid);
    }

    private static OnCardClickListener mListener;


    public void setOnCardClickListener(OnCardClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        CardView mCard;

        public ItemHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.bell_card);
            mCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            boolean isValid = (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION);
            mListener.onCardClick(v, position, isValid);
        }
    }
}
```

Далее в активити используем так:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements SomeAdapter.OnCardClickListener {

    RecyclerView mList;
    SomeAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAdapter = new SomeAdapter(mData);
        mAdapter.setOnCardClickListener(this);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCardClick(View view,final int position, boolean isValid) {

        if (isValid) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1: return true;
            default: return false;
            }
        }
   }

}
```

В каждой активити может быть своя реализация действий в переопределенном методе `onCardClick()`. Колбэк передает в активити `View`, по которому кликнули, позицию в адаптере и признак валидности этой позиции. Вы можете передавать из адаптера и другие произвольные данные, которые вам могут требоваться.