# Как получить данные из RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть список. Нужно при нажатии на элемент получить название и вывести в EditText. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: EditText в активити? Тогда лучше всего прокинуть интерфейс до активити и при кликах на айтемах передавать текст, в активити из колбэка принимать этот текст и назначать в EditText/ Как [прокинуть интерфейс](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/567477/177345).

Comment: В фрагменте если по точнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написал @pavlofff, можно сделать решить проблему с помощью интерфейса обратного вызова.

Сначала надо создать интерфейс (название интерфейса может быть любым):

**FillEditText**

```
public interface FillEditText {
    void fillEditText(String text);
}
```

Затем, реализуем его в родительской для фрагмента активности:

*Предположу, что родительская активность называется MainActivity.*

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FillEditText {
    @Override
    public void fillEditText(String text) {
        mEditText.setText(text);
    }
    ...
}
```

Во фрагменте переопределяем метод onAttach(Context) (можно переопределить метод onAttach(activity), но он **depricated**):

*Предположу, что фрагмент называется MyFragment.*

**MyFragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private FillEditText fillEditTextCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        //сделаем проверку, что context реализует наш интерфейс
        if(context instanceof FillEditText) {
            fillEditTextCallback = (FillEditText) context;
        } else {
            //Здесь что-нибудь делает, чтобы сообщить,
            //что context не реализует интерфейс FillEditText (например, кинуть Exception)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Теперь можно во ViewHolder реализовать интерфейс View.OnClickListener и передавать текст в родительскую активность.

*Предположу, что класс ViewHolder реализовать внутри MyFragment и его название MyViewHolder.*

**ViewHolder**

```
private calss MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView labelTextView;
    ...
    //Конструктор может отличаться от этого,
    //главное добавить onClickListener, чтобы обрабатывались клики
    public MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        ...
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fillEditTextCallback.fillEditText(labelTextView.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо еще метод привязки интерфейса к получателю (сеттер для экземпляра, реализующего интерфейс).

Comment: Нажатия не обрабатываются

Comment: @РасулA-ев обновил ответ. Надо в конструкторе MyViewHolder для itemView добавить onClickListener.

Comment: Я добавил onclicklistener, всеравно не обрабатываются

Comment: Нужно еще сделать такой же листенер и для вашего колбэка, я же написал уже. У вас приемник и получатель никак не связаны сейчас

Comment: @pavlofff как же? В методе onAttach фрагмент получает Context, затем приводит его к интерфейсу FillEditText. А MainActivity реализует этот интерфейс.

Comment: @РасулA-ев выложите ваш код, я без него не могу сказать в чём ошибка.

Comment: Все сам разобрался. Спасибо всем за ответы

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        //любой onClick на view. Тут TexView для примера
        viewHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
     //...
     Тут и обрабатывать
     ListData - массив с данными которыми заполнен RecyclerView
     String text = ListData.get(i);//получили текст по нажатой позиции и затем делаем с ним что надо. Можно добавить в EditText
    };
    }
```

Все это делается в Адаптере в методе onBindViewHolder. Если дадите код адаптера, то на нем покажу

Comment: момент передачи в активити не раскрыт как то ..

Comment: @pavlofff Ну я не знаю как у него в адаптере. Если глобальный статик то можно просто присвоить, а иначе через контекст можно достучаться. Это от случая зависит

Comment: хорошей практикой признан интерфейс обратного вызова, как в примере из комментария к вопросу.

Comment: хммм. Посмотрю. Я либо это называю иначе либо не знаю вообще такого. Спасибо