# Как передать значения в View на Layout из RecyclerView.Adapter.class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adapter, recyclerview.adapter

Класс унаследованный от RecyclerView.Adapter имеет кнопку на макете(контейнере), при нажатии которой я должен передать значение в TextView которая не находится на этом макете(контейнере).

```
public class RecyclerAdapterForTrainingConstructor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterForTrainingConstructor.myVH>{

public void onBindViewHolder(final myVH myVH, int position) {
  myVH.okExercise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//тут нужно поменять текст в TextView которое находится на экране возле RecyclerView
}
  public static class myVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    Button okExercise;
  myVH(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    okExercise = itemView.findViewById(R.id.okExercise);
}
}
```

это собственно класс Адаптера.
Мои предположения через Intent, но у меня не получилось. или же создавать экземпляр класса привязанного к этому экрану в Адаптере и вызывать там смену текста. так же не получилось. Примеров не нашел.

Comment: просто прокидываете колбэк из адаптера в активити, примеров огромное количество. Например [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/567477/177345)

Comment: @pavlifff спасибо, идею я понял, пример отличный!

Comment: @pavlofff  Методом который вы прислали я не могу получить доступ к кнопке на этом CardVIew. он срабатывает только когда я кликаю на область карточки либо на некликабельные элементы карточки. Даже при условии что я указывают конкретное айди. что может быть причиной? сделал все строго по вашему примеру

Comment: В общем. по какой то причине на кнопку этот метод не работает. пришлось создать ImageView. Так работает

Comment: очевидно, что "мой метод" здесь не причем. Проблема в том, как виджеты регистрируют на себя клики, то есть, например кардвью стоит выше в иерархии виджетов и первым перехватывает клик. Здесь нужно разбираться с разметкой, атрибутом clickable и вот этим вот всем. "Мой метод" просто передает событие клика из адаптера в активити, почему какой-то виджет не регистрирует на себе клик - совершенно другая проблема и если вы не можете ее решить самостоятельно, создайте новый вопрос.